# AngularJs Get the value of the selected option

Tags: angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-ng-change

How can i get the value of the selected option on the ng-change "ReadData"
Template is an array of Title, Id, and body

```
<select class="form-control" id="inputEmail" 
    ng-change="ReadData(Template.Title)" 
    ng-model="email.Template" name="inputEmail" 
    ng-options="b.Id as b.Title for b in Template">
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work:

ng-change="ReadData(Template[$index].Title)"

Answer (score 0):

Since your `select` is bound (by means of `ngModel`) to `email.Template`, you can access it's value from there. E.g.:

```
<select ... ng-change="ReadData(email.Template)" ...
```

Note though that, as a result of how you define `ngOptions`, `email.Template` will be bound to the teplate's id. If you want it to be bound to the whole template object itself (so you can use `email.Template.Title` for example), change your code like this:

```
<select ... ng-options="b as b.Title for b in Template" 
        ... ng-change="ReadData(email.Template.Title)" ...
```

Comment: email and template are not in the same scope

Comment: I don't really get your point. You are referencing both from your `<select>` so you have access to both. Maybe creating a fiddle would save time to you and to candidate answerers as well...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `ng-change` to get selected data, in `<select>` your `ng-model` bind will hold selected option. You can just get that value in your ng-change;

```
<select class="form-control" id="inputEmail"
    ng-change="onOptionChange()" 
    ng-model="email.Template" name="inputEmail" 
    ng-options="b.Id as b.Title for b in Template">
</select>
```

Here is a **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cemozer/SdkpD/2/)**

---

EDIT: Also if you want to entire selected Template object, change you ng-options to this:

```
ng-options="b.Title for b in Template"
```

This will assign b to email.Template, not just b.Id.

Comment: i know but i have to get the id too on your jsfiddle i don't have Selected: and the selected item's title but the id

Comment: I don't think this can be done, since ng-options has its own isolate scope, you can't get data like that if it's not exposed by directive itself. You must use entire object in ng-model and on ng-change make proper assignments.